# Beginner SQL - joining tables which have identifier in both tables

Tags: sql

I currently have two tables - `ShopReturnHeader`, and `ShopReturnApprover`.

In the `ShopReturnApprover` table, there is an unique identifier column, which gives an `ID` to the `ApproverName` column beside it, e.g., 1 = John

In the `ShopReturnHeader` table, the same identifier column exists, however the column with the `ApproverName` does not exist.

How do I go about bringing over the `ApproverName` column from the `ShopReturnApprover` table, so it can match up with the unique identifier rows in the `ShopReturnHeader` table?

Appreciate any assistance.

Thanks!

Comment: you should lookup : table joins

Comment: _"In the `ShopReturnHeader` table, the same identifier column exists"_ <- what is the identifier? Is it for the row in `ShopReturnHeader` or is a foreign key identifier for `ShopReturnApprover (ID)`?

Comment: provide more context like relevant table columns and how they connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ShopReturnApprover.ID, ShopReturnApprover.ApproverName , ShopReturnHeader.ID
FROM ShopReturnApprover
INNER JOIN ShopReturnHeader
ON ShopReturnHeader.ID=ShopReturnApprover.ID;
```

Do you means want table joins ? Hope this help you

Comment: That's what I want - thanks!! I forgot you could use SELECT to bring in a column from another table :L